# Using concat() function, is specific cases

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I need concatenate regexp pattern pieces, for this pattern, I use C-style Escape `E`.

If use  concatenation operator `||`, works:

```
E'a{'||2||'}'
```

does not make much sense, but just interes, how to concatenate same, using `concat()` function ?

Comment: What is wrong with the [manual explanation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)?

Comment: You keep on showing only fragments of your real queries and failing to show the error output. I don't know how to say it any other way.

Comment: ClodoaldoNeto --- That is, in case when needed concatenate `non-string` input, just operator `||` must be use, right?   CraigRinger --- But why is necessary show full query here? question is just: "function concat() can or not concatenate C-style Escape `E` with string ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is this: C-style escapes are just another way to input string literals. When you concatenate strings, be it with the `||` operator or with the [`concat()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) function (Postgres 9.1+), the method *how* individual strings were input is **irrelevant**.

In addition to that, literals of other types (like the numeric constant `2` in your example) are coerced to `text` automatically.

On top of that, your example does not exhibit any characters with a special meaning in escape strings (like `\`).

```
SELECT E'a{' || 2 || '}';

SELECT concat(E'a{', 2, '}');
```

So, the `E` is totally irrelevant in this particular example.

Since you mention regexp patterns: those tend to have `\` in them, which have to be escaped with `\` in `E''` notation:

```
SELECT E'\\.' || 2 || '\.';
```

The modern way is *not* to use escape strings at all if not necessary. That's why Postgres switched to [`standard_conforming_strings = ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) with PostgreSQL 9.1. That is the setting I tested with.